# Can't connect bridging header to iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

So I've connected a couple Objective C frameworks to my project, imported them through my bridging file, and having some issues with references.

As far as I know, i've connected it properly and I've scoured around for other solutions for this, but I cant seem to find anything that works.

[image]

This is the error I'm receiving, but I have the header connected through my build settings, here.

[image]

I'm not sure what else can be done to try and force my project to understand where my bridge is (The file paths are correct).

Comment: Your bridging-header.h file should be completely empty except having a few #import calls. So there should be no class definition, etc. Is that what you have?

Answer (score 2):

One recommendation is to delete your Bridging-Header file and have the app "Auto-create" one for you. This way it's automatically hooked up correctly by Xcode.

To auto-create a new one after you delete your old one:

1) Choose New File, select Source\Cocoa Touch Class.

2) Choose NSObject class and make sure the language is set to Objective C

3) Name the file "Bridging-Header.h"

4) When you add the file to your project a popup should appear that asks you if you want to create a bridging header file. Say Yes.

5) A perkomatic-Bridgin-Header.h file should be created and you can delete your Bridging-Header.m files.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the Bridging Header file is placed under a folder inside your project folder, with the same name of your project. Have you tried changing the path to perkomatic/perkomatic-Bridgin-Header.h?

You may also have to check this configuration on the Unit Test target.

Comment: I've made sure the file is included in both build settings, and it's looking in the sub directory already @ perkomatic/perkomatic-Bridgin-Header.h

Comment: I've missed a 'g' on my path, actually it is: perkomatic/perkomatic-Bridgin**g**-Header.h